# Where is this scene happening in season 1's episode 2?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

I am referring to the scene in season 1's episode 2 where Sean Bean has to kill the wolf because of the Queen's order.

Are they at the King's Landing or somewhere on the way? Why are his children with him? Are they going to King's landing as well? If so, why isn't his wife going with him?

I am having difficulty figuring out **where** exactly the scene beginning with the wolf attacking the prince is happening.

Comment: Maybe you aren't paying the show the attention it deserves. Yes, they are _on the way_ to the King's Landing where Ned is supposed to be the Hand to Robert. And Catelyn (Ned's wife) is not coming along as she is nursing Bran to health back at Winterfell.

Comment: @KeyBrdBasher I think you should post this as an answer!

Comment: @KeyBrdBasher I knew having dinner while watching the Series was a bad idea :)

Comment: @BobbyAlexander: Second that! Either shift your dinner timing or stop having dinner altogether ;)

Comment: @KeyBrdBasher Also, this was after a House MD season 4 marathon!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> When this is happening - are they at King's Landing or somewhere on the way?

They are *on the way* to the King's Landing. To be more precise, they are near the [Inn at the Crossroads](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Inn_at_the_Crossroads).

> Why are his children with him? Are they going to King's landing as well? If so, why isn't his wife going with him?

Ned had recently been asked by Robert to be the *King's Hand*. He is accompanied by his two daughters Arya and Sansa. 
His wife is back at Winterfell, where she is nursing back their son Bran to health. He went into a state of coma after being pushed off a window by Jamie Lannister.

*As for your last statement, the entire incident of Nymeria biting Joffrey happened by a riverside which is somewhere near the Crossroads Inn.*

Comment: Well.. I thought she was staying back because of her son but I got the impression that she wasnt going to go anyway because in earlier scenes, she asks Ned not to go and in one scene in the room with her son, she tells Ned the last time he went off he came back with another woman's son. If she was to join him once her son got well then she wouldnt have been so depressed. This is the reason for my confusion.

Comment: There is no way to tell if Catelyn would join Ned at the King's Landing. Moreover, the full recovery of Bran might take months if not years. In the current scenario any mother would choose to do what Catelyn does. As for her misgivings of Ned coming back with a bastard, you got to understand that this incident happened many years ago when Ned was young and susceptible.

Comment: I know this is late but I am just reading the book and it turns out my assumption was right: In the book Ned asks his wife to stay back in Winterfell to handle its affairs on his behalf. It is not very evident in the TV Series but Catelyn wouldn't have gone with Ned even if Bran was fine.

Answer (score 5):

Ned Stark is travelling to King's Landing with his daughters Arya and Sansa, and the royal family. They have stopped at an inn along the way and the children are out playing near the river.

Catelyn (Ned's wife) is not there because she has stayed at Winterfell to look after Bran, who is paralysed after being pushed out of a window by Jaime Lannister.